# How to samba automatically add user and share they home?

Tags: samba

*Linux OpenSuse 12.3 , samba server 3.6.12 .*

My samba is configured and working with `security = user` and today is used only for two users where I was added manually at passwd and smbpasswd.
This server have nothing of windows AD configured or authenticated .

Now I need to use this server with other users, like per user home folder...
where each user what access this server will see they own folder and able to write anything there.

I already configured the [homes] option, which work fine for users what already exists.
Of course, not work for new users which I don't added at passwd and smbpasswd;.

How I automatically add new users "on demand" ?  in someway where we don't need to create a explicit password? 
I've configured the `add user script` but they don't run when a differ user try access the server.

**What is my objective :**

- The name of samba server is jdiserver.
- Let's suppose the user John will access this server by windows `\\jdiserver` at first time.
- If is they first access and the user doesn't exists at linux, the user should automatically added at passwd and smbpasswd
- they homedir should be created and shared at they connection .
- All this , without asking passwords...

Is this possible? 
What I missing?

This is my configuration today:

```
[global]
    workgroup = XXX
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    printing = bsd
    map to guest = Bad User
    include = /etc/samba/dhcp.conf
    logon path = \\%L\profiles\.msprofile
    logon home = \\%L\%U\.9xprofile
    logon drive = P:
    usershare allow guests = No
    domain logons = No
    domain master = No
    netbios name = jdiserver
    server string = jdiserver
    wins server = 101.0.0.1 101.0.0.2
    wins support = No
    deadtime = 5
    security = user

    add user script = sh /etc/samba/adduser.sh %u 
    machine password timeout = 1800

[homes]
  comment = Home Directories
  valid users = %S, %D%w%S
  browseable = No
  read only = No
  inherit acls = Yes
  path = /mnt/temp_disk/WIN_BACKUP/%S
  force user = nobody
  force group = nobody
```